# Не получается отфильтровать сводную таблицу на python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pivot

Есть таблица Excel, из которой я сделал сводную. Необходимо отфильтровать по коду tnved4(работает) и по месяцам, годам. Загвоздка заключается в том, что год и месяцы в Excel сохранены как текст. Есть ли какое-то решение без изменения формата данных в Excel?

**Текущий код выдает ошибку: KeyError: '2022'**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Загрузка данных из таблицы
df = pd.read_excel('ВПР+доработка5.xlsx')


# Создание сводной таблицы
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["tnved4", "Блок"], columns=["year", "month"], values="Stoim", aggfunc=np.sum)

tnved4_values = [6204]
years_filter = ['2022']  # Фильтр по году в текстовом формате
months_filter = ['01', '02', '03']  # Фильтр по месяцам в текстовом формате

filtered_data = pivot_table.loc[tnved4_values, years_filter, months_filter]


filtered_data.to_excel('filtered_data1.xlsx')
```

[image: Таблица Excel]

Comment: вы уверены, что правильно представляете себе работу метода `loc`?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что вам нужно что-то типа: `filtered_data = pivot_table.loc[(pivot_table["tnved4"].isin(tnved4_values)) & (pivot_table["year"].isin( years_filter)) & (pivot_table["month"].isin(months_filter))]`